# Can we add subject 'you' in the imperative sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, word-order, imperative-sentences

Can we add subject 'you' in the imperative sentence?

> Without studying regularly, don't expect to get high   marks.
>   → Without studying regularly, **you** don't expect to get high marks.

Comment: Once you add the second person pronoun as in your example, the sentence no longer reveals the imperative mood. To reveal the imperative with _you,_ it would have to be: "Don't you expect to get high marks!" or some such. This is highly colloquial. We usually don't see a subject in a sentence in the imperative.

Answer (score 2):

> Without studying regularly, you don't expect to get high marks.

By putting *you* in the position that  you have, you have changed the sentence from the imperative to the indicative.<sup>1</sup> The *you* here is  the generalized you that means *one* or *a person*.

To maintain the imperative mood, you could put the *you* after the *don't* to get

> Without studying regularly, don't you  expect to get high marks.

However, this is highly stylistic/stilted/possibly old-fashioned. In other words, it would not be common to encounter  it in everyday English.

One the other hand, "don't you forget" about this song:

[Don't you (forget about me)](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0jlHz0wF0Ig) (YouTube video)

Here, it's usage in art  does not indicate common usage in everyday English; it just goes with the rest of the song  in wording, style, rhythm, stress, et al., but the imperative mood is easily recognizable by the native speaker.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the case if you read or say the sentence normally without any unusual stress on *you*. Even if you stress *you*, you are still in the indicative. But if you "separate" *you* from the flow of the sentence, and turn it into the *vocative you* (*calling out* to the person "you") , as in

> Without studying regularly, *you!* (*you there!*)(*hey! you!*), don't expect to get high marks.

then you have an imperative.

Answer (score -1):

When you insert a ***you*,** you have to change the verb to ***can't:***

→ Without studying regularly, you can't expect to get high marks.

But it is not an imperative sentence anymore, it's just informative then.